# mysqli select query does not work propley

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i'm trying to pull out all rows from mysql table.
I have created this code

```
function getAllRows($tablename){
            $query = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `".$tablename."`");
            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result($results);
            while($query->fetch())
            {
                $rows[] = $results;
            }
            return $rows;
        }
```

but I recive this error:
`( ! ) Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in D:\wamp64\www\easyApi\configuration.php on line 16`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: if you wanna bind one row, select that row onlyt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must bind the same number of column you get suing the select
could be you select * return more then a column
try adding the right number of var to your bind_result

```
$query = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT col1, col2 FROM `".$tablename."`");
```

...

```
$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);
```

Comment: what should I do if i want to output all columns? instand of print all table's columns?

Comment: you can use mysqi_fetch_row, mysqli_fetch_array  or mysqli_fetch_associative and interate over the result  .. php man  http://php.net/manual/it/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php  or http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php or http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php  .. but this is another question ..